# Symbolicating addresses programmatically

Tags: ios, macos, dwarf, symbolicate

I am looking for a way to symbolicate external app symbols (iOS) inside my own application (macOS), assuming I have the DSYM and system symbols.

Xcode symbolicates both app addresses as well as system framework addresses (UIKit, Foundation, etc.)
`atos` requires an image file and can symbolicate addresses from that image.

I am looking to symbolicate a large number of addresses in my own app. The addresses represent stack traces at various points in time. I would like to symbolicate the system framework addresses as well.

I found [atosl](https://github.com/facebookarchive/atosl), which uses `dwarf.h` and `libdwarf.h` to reimplement `atos` to varying degrees of success—however this seems like a very low–level approach.

Are there any other ways to symbolicate a large number of addresses at once?

Comment: Here is symbolication I use in tests (requires XCTest): https://github.com/avito-tech/Mixbox/blob/db3206c95b71f35ae6032ff9b0baff13026608f4/Frameworks/TestsFoundation/Reporting/FileLineForFailureProvider/StackTrace/ExtendedStackTraceEntryFromStackTraceEntryConverterImpl.swift

Answer (score 0):

Here is symbolication I use in tests (requires XCTest): https://github.com/avito-tech/Mixbox/blob/db3206c95b71f35ae6032ff9b0baff13026608f4/Frameworks/TestsFoundation/Reporting/FileLineForFailureProvider/StackTrace/ExtendedStackTraceEntryFromStackTraceEntryConverterImpl.swift

I use the code to highlight failures in tests in Xcode without requiring testers to pass `file: StaticString = #file, line: UInt = #line` everywhere. The code is less readable with this boilerplate, and also there is not much reason for such boilerplate, because ideally Xcode should be able to highlight stacktrace of test failure...

Note that there is an issue. If you do not have sources on the machine that executes the code, it doesn't symbolicate. Maybe it can be fixed quickly, I didn't even tried.

Also there are comments in the code about other options: atos, lldb, CoreSymbolication. I think `CoreSymbolication` is what you want to use. The solution I gave you is simple, more dependent on XCTest, less configurable, has some other flaws.

Comment: It doesn't work anymore, I think since I've updated to Catalina. It has some changes in security.